# Ansible - Access hosts (list) in groups variable (dictionary) via regex or json_query (+JSME functions) on group_name (key)

Tags: ansible, jinja2

we are having dynamic group names in our inventory file, that are based on a naming convention. For these I would like to access the hosts of these to iterate through all of them in order to create a string out of it (eg. comma seperated).

As an example:

```
    [misbe_test_a]
    host1
    host2

    [misbe_test_b]
    host2
    host3
    host4
```

The variable would be a dictionary, which contains per item a list:

```
    "misbe_test_a": [
        "host1",
        "host2"
    ],
    "misbe_test_b": [
        "host2",
        "host3",
        "host4"
    ]
```

What of course works out for one specific group:

```
    {% for host in (groups["misbe_test_a"] | unique) %}{{ host }}{% endfor %}
```

However I need to access all of the groups without knowing what is followed by misbe_. This solution will of course not work out:

```
    {% for host in (groups["misbe_*"] | unique) %}{{ host }}{% endfor %}
```

Any ideas how I could solve that with a one liner? What I would like to omit is the following (in addition it would add host2 twice to my string > as in different groups):

```
    {% for group_name in (groups | select('match','misbe.*') | list | unique) %}
      {% for host in groups[group_name] %}
        {{ host }}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}"
```

**EDIT**

What about using json_query for this, is there any possibility to query the key of the dictionary and then access the items of the list?

This one would work for one group:

```
    {{ groups | json_query('misbe_test_a') | list | join(',') }}
```

Unfortunately I do not know how to select they key in the dictionary with JSME functions (eg. starts_with or contains http://jmespath.org/specification.html#functions).

Answer (score 0):

For example this way:

- iterate over `groups` and select the ones you want with a regular expression
- concatenate the lists of hosts for each of the above groups
- select unique hosts for printing from that concatenated list

```
{% set ns = namespace(all_hosts=[]) %}
{% for group_name in (groups | select('match','misbe.*')) %}
{% set ns.all_hosts = ns.all_hosts + groups[group_name] %}
{% endfor %}
{% for host in (ns.all_hosts | unique) %}{{ host }}{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I am aware that I could store my hosts in a seperate variable and then filter them for uniqueness and iterate through them. But isn't this possible with a one liner - instead of using seperate variables? Based on a regex or filter?

Comment: You can remove new line characters and write the above code in one line.

Comment: I am aware of that, but a there most be a shorter way to do this?